# Checking if in member function context

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, member

#### TL;DR

Is there a way to detect using macros/templates/magic if a function was called from a member function or from a free/static function?

#### Some context

For debugging purposes, I implemented a macro called `TRACE(fmt, ...)` which writes to file a message with formatted output, with extra information for context (e.g. timestamp, file, function). For an example, calling `TRACE("Hello %s", "world!");` will write `(2/10/2019 22:32:58 func@file.cpp:27) Hello world!`.

Recently, I noticed that in member functions I usually print the address of the object (`this`) to have some extra context and differentiate between calls to members of different objects.

As this need is very common, I'd want to improve my `TRACE` macro to output `this` if invoked from a member function. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to implement this check - "is invoked from a context of a member?"

To clarify, I want to implement a macro TRACE that acts as before in non-member functions, but in member functions the output message will be different and more similar to `(2/10/2019 20:32:58 func@file.cpp:27 0x80808080) Hello world!`.

To do that, I think I need to differentiate between "macro is invoked from a member function" and "macro is invoked from a non-member function".

#### My Questions

1. Can I somehow check if my macro was called from a member function or not?
2. If not, can I somehow implement the `TRACE` macro I want to have?

Note that I use GCC, but I'd prefer to have a cross-platform solution.

#### Things I tried

At first, I tried to check if `this` is defined, but as it is a keyword it is always "not defined" (`defined(this)` is false). Moreover, if I try to use `this` outside of a member function, I get a compilation error. In GCC it is `invalid use of 'this' in non-member function`. Therefore, it seems that the solution will need to get this information in a more hack-y way, but I'm not sure what it should be.

As an example to how my `TRACE` macro looks like, you can see [this link](https://godbolt.org/z/zIFLTy). I wish that using `TRACE` in a member function (e.g. in the ctor of `A`) will "automatically" print the value of `this`, without needing to pass it explicitly to the macro

Comment: You should do a [mcve] to show what do you want

Comment: @Amadeus I've updated the question a sample in Compiler Explorer which I hope will clarify my goal, but I don't know how to do what I want to do - hence the question and the initial lack of an example

Comment: `this` is not "defined" because the preprocessor only knows about `#define`d names. The fact that it is a keyword is irrelevant. You can `#define` keywords, although it is really not a good idea, so if you were to `#define this this`, then `defined(this)` would be true. Of course, it would be true anywhere after the `#define` so that doesn't help you decide whether the current location is inside a member function or not.

Comment: I can't see any way to do this. Guess you'll just need a separate `TRACE_THIS` macro.